# A problem For the boundary value problem, $y''+\lambda y=0$, $y(-π)=y(π)$ , $y’(-π)=y’(π)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the boundary value problem,
$y''+\lambda y=0$
$y(-π)=y(π)$   ,   $y’(-π)=y’(π)$
to each eigenvalue $\lambda$, there corresponds

1. Only one eigenfunction
2. Two eigenfunctions
3. Two linearly independent eigenfunctions
4. Two orthogonal eigenfunctions

I have tried to solve the problem but could not get my calculations right. Can somebody help?

Comment: Surely you know the general solution of the equation $y''+\lambda y=0$. Once this is written down, you might want to examine points 1. to 4.

Answer (score 1):

This is elementary. Find for each $\lambda$ general form of a solution of the equation without boundary conditions, and try to apply the boundry condition. 
You won't get stuck in the calcualtions again, as there is almost nothing to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247730/consider-the-following-sturm-liouville-problem/247836#247836). First solve the differential equation

$$ y(x)=c_1\,\sin \left( \sqrt {\lambda}x \right) + c_2\,\cos\left( \sqrt {\lambda}x \right) .$$
Applying the boundary conditions to the solution results in the two equations

$$ y(\pi)=y(-\pi) \implies 2{ c_1}\,\sin \left( \sqrt {\lambda}\pi  \right)= 0 \rightarrow (1) $$

$$y'(\pi)=y'(-\pi)\implies 2{c_2}\sqrt{\lambda}\sin \left( \sqrt {\lambda}\pi  \right) = 0 \rightarrow (2), $$

where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants. From $(1)$, since $c_1$ is an arbitrary constant, then we have

$$ \sin\left( \sqrt {\lambda}\pi \right) = 0 \implies \sqrt {\lambda}\pi = n\pi \implies \lambda = n^2. $$

Eq. $(2)$ gives the same eigenvalues with the other eigenvalue $\lambda=0$, since $c_2$ is an arbitrary constant. So, can you find the eigenvectors now and answer the question?

**Note:** This problem is known as "The Sturm-Liouville Eigenvalue Problems". One of the properties of this kind of problems is that "for each eigenvalue $\lambda_n$ there exists an eigenfunction $\phi_n$.

Comment: The explanation *since $c_1$ is an arbitrary constant* and the line after it are misleading. One should first assume that $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)\ne0$, show that this leads to a contradiction, then proceed with the case $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=0$. Similar remark about *since $c_2$ is an arbitrary constant*.