# Green function Sturm Liouville equation problem ...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with this new one, I don't even know how to start...

$$Ly=-y''-y$$

$$y(0)=y(1)=0$$

I started doing this exercise and came to the conclusion that the result is given to us by

$$G(x, s)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
c_2\sin(x) & x<s\\ 
c_3\cos(x)+c_4\sin(x) & s<x \\
\end{matrix}\right.$$

The solution on the book is:

$$G(x, s)=\frac{1}{\sin 1}\left\{\begin{matrix}
\sin(x)\sin(1-s) & 0\leq x\leq s \\ 
\sin(1-x)\sin(s) & s\leq x\leq 1 \\
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: What course are you taking that covers these integral and differential equations?

Comment: Linear analisys

Comment: possible duplicate of [Small doubt Green's functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416433/small-doubt-greens-functions)

Answer (score 0):

This form is the result of the additional conditions that $G(1,s)=0$ and that $x\mapsto G(x,s)$ be continuous, also at $x=s$.

The first gives the relation
$$
0=c_3\cos(1)+c_4\sin(1)
$$
so that $c_3=c_5\sin(1)$, $c_4=-c_5\cos(1)$. Inserting that for $x>s$ gives
$$
G(x,s)=c_5(\sin(1)\cos(x)-\cos(1)\sin(x))=c_5\sin(1-x).
$$
The continuity results in
$$
c_2\sin(s)=G(s,s)=c_5\sin(1-s)
$$
Thus $c_2=c_6\sin(1-s)$ and $c_5=c_6\sin(s)$. This then gives the second cited form of Greens function.